# Обработка массива данных с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
У меня существует список конкретных задач с полями "дата выполнения", "Пользователь", "Наименование организации", "Задача".
У конкретного пользователя за каждый месяц есть выполненные задачи по каждой организации (в определённый месяц у конкретной организации не было выполненных задач пользователем)

То есть привести к такому виду:
Список Месяцев, в нём список Пользователей, в нём словарь (Имя организации, Количество задач, выполненных пользователем)

Прошу помочь составить Linq-запрос :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Task> testList = new List<Task>();
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 11, 1), "User1", "TaskAB", "AAA"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 11, 5), "User2", "TaskTask", "ERT"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 09, 13), "User3", "Task599", "ERT"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 09, 13), "User5", "Task81", "BBS"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 03, 23), "User4", "TaskZ", "YOLO"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 10, 3), "User9", "TaskEE", "RA1"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 10, 5), "User9", "TaskFT", "RA1"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 10, 26), "User8", "Task555", "RA1"));
        testList.Add(new Task(new DateTime(2016, 09, 2), "User1", "TaskFT", "BBS"));
        foreach (var task in testList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.EndDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + task.UserName + " " + task.CompanyName + " " + task.FinishedTaskName);
        }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public DateTime EndDate
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string FinishedTaskName
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string CompanyName
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public Task(DateTime endDate, string userName, string finishedTaskName, string companyName)
        {
            EndDate = endDate;
            UserName = userName;
            FinishedTaskName = finishedTaskName;
            CompanyName = companyName;
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VRLi9m

Comment: В данном вопросе Вы решаете задачу группирования данных. Рекомендую ознакомиться с [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397926.aspx).

Comment: А какого рода помощь вам нужна? «Оформить» — это ведь не «сделать за меня», правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу людей знающих проверить мое собственное решение задачи

```
    var dic = (
    from t in testList
    group t by t.EndDate.Month into monthGroup
        select new
        {
        Month = monthGroup.Key, Entries = (
            from emp in monthGroup
            group emp by emp.UserName into empGroup
                select new
                {
                Employee = empGroup.Key, Entries = (
                    from company in empGroup
                    group company by company.CompanyName into companyGroup
                        select new
                        {
                        Company = companyGroup.Key, taskCount = companyGroup.Count()})
                        .ToDictionary(ent => ent.Company, ent => ent.taskCount)})
                .ToDictionary(ent => ent.Employee, ent => ent.Entries)})
        .ToDictionary(ent => ent.Month, ent => ent.Entries);
```

Comment: Вероятно, можно сделать немного проще через [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).